# Showing magento shipping cost, gift wrap cost, and total in checkout success page

Tags: magento-1.8, onepage-checkout

actually i want to show shipping cost, gift wrap cost, and order total amount in checkout success page, found that success.phtml file, but not sure to type the code, anyone experience with it ?

currentlly just found the subtotal

```
<?php echo Mage::helper("core")->currency($order_details->subtotal) ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get the details by the following,

```
    $orderSubTotal = $order_details->subtotal;
    $shipping_amount = $order_details->shipping_amount;
    $gift_cards_amount = $order_details->gift_cards_amount;
    $grand_total = $order_details->grand_total;
```

here `$order_details` as below,

```
$order_details = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderid);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, it all works except the gift cards amount @Helphin